# Erro ao utilizar replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando o replace, mas quando passo o número 1 ou 12 para ele da erro.
Por exemplo :

```
$(this).data('qtde').replace(/\./g, "")
```

Passando o valor 1.223,44 funciona, quando passo 1 da o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).replace is not a function at
>   HTMLTableRowElement. (Elaborar.js?v=08022018:792) at
>   Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.js:362) at jQuery.fn.init.each
>   (jquery-3.2.1.js:157) at HTMLInputElement.gravar
>   (Elaborar.js?v=08022018:782) at HTMLInputElement.dispatch
>   (jquery-3.2.1.js:5206) at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle
>   (jquery-3.2.1.js:5014)

Comment: Qual o erro exibido?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).replace is not a function
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (Elaborar.js?v=08022018:792)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.js:362)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.2.1.js:157)
    at HTMLInputElement.gravar (Elaborar.js?v=08022018:782)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.js:5206)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.2.1.js:5014)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente tornar o número uma string:

```
$(this).data('qtde').toString();
$(this).data('qtde').replace(/\./g, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Cara, tenho uma outra solução que é adicionar uma função `replaceAll` em variáveis do tipo `string`. Acredito ser seu caso, já que tem virgula e ponto. Pelo que entendi, você quer dar `replace` apenas no ponto. Isso já é o suficiente. Veja o exemplo:

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = String.prototype.replaceAll || function(needle, replacement) {
    return this.split(needle).join(replacement);
};

var numbers = ['1.399,00', '1,00', '12,00', '1.399.244,00', '1', '12', '150.000,34'];
for (n in numbers){
  numbers[n] = numbers[n].replaceAll('.', '');
  console.log(numbers[n]);
  console.log("Normalizado: ", Number(numbers[n].replaceAll(',', '.')).toFixed(2) )
}
```

Comment: Então Guilherme, meu problema é que as vezes o usuário pode inserir 1 e também pode inserir 1,23...

Comment: Editei. Coloquei diversas possibilidades, inclusive o 1. Pode fazer com qualquer numero que tenha ponto e virgula, ele vai remover todos os pontos.